# How to add the script approval proactively in Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins

Is there any way to add the script approval proactively in Jenkins. The reason for this question, in my current team we have two Jenkins instances. The first one is more of a playground and the second one have all the actual CI pipelines.

All the scripts which need approval are already caught and approved in the playground Jenkins instance. When I use the same method in the second instance can I already provide approval for these methods even before the pipeline/job is run (and thus ensuring that my pipeline not fail due to script approval).